# iPad - dropdown navigation better practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

I have a web application that is expected to run on iPad. I do not wish to create a "dropdown" HTML element for navigation (ie. a select element) since I have plenty of real estate. I want to use my existing desktop-style "hover over then select" type navigation, but replace the hover event with a tap.

I only need to support mobile Safari for iPad, though other browser support could be a plus.

Here's how the nav is structured:

```
<nav id="main_navigation">
  <ul>
    <li>
        <a id="nav_home" href="/index.jsp">home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menuHasDrop" id="selected">
        <a id="parent" href="/parent.jsp">parent</a>
        <span class="navArrow"></span>
        <ul>
          <li><a id="foo" href="/foo.jsp">foo</a></li>
          <li><a id="bar" href="/bar.jsp">bar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>   
    <li>
        <a id="baz" href="baz.jsp">baz</a>
    </li>      
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And here's how I'm detecting and enabling touch:

```
fc.enableTouch = function() {  
  (function() {
    try {
      document.createEvent('TouchEvent');
      fc.touchEnabled = true;
    } catch(e) {}
  })();

  if (fc.touchEnabled) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

      // disable clicks on parents
      var $menus = $('.menuHasDrop');
      $menus.on('click', '>a', function(e){
        return false;
      })

      // listen for clicks on others          
      $('#main_navigation').on('click', $menus, function(e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.parent().children('ul').length > 0) {
          $menus.find('ul').hide();
          $this.toggleClass('expanded');
          if($this.hasClass('expanded')) {  
            $this.find('ul').show();
          }
        }
      });
    });
  } else {
    // console.log('not detecting touch');
  }  
}();
```

The "expanded" class is just a flag. I could set a flag another way, but it shouldn't matter much.

So, this all "works"... but there are two things bugging me:

1. There's a flicker of a shadow of some sort over the parent nav when I click it. I'm sure it's an OS "clicked a link" indicator, but it's not explicitly provided by CSS or the JavaScript. If anybody has seen such a thing, do you know how to disable it?
2. Every now and then on a fluke it seems, the UL representing the sub-menu seems to appear, go away, and appear again. Again, I don't THINK the logic itself would be able to cause this, so it might be browser-specific.

Other useful background information: there are always one or more content areas being refreshed via ajax calls, but the page itself is not being refreshed and the navigation area does not have any functions acting on it during the request.

I guess what I'm asking more than a code review is: "Are these just iOS quirks that I have to live with?" and "is there a definitive better practice for touch-enabling dropdowns?" Secondarily, all "I see a problem with your code" advice will be welcomed and appreciated. :)

Comment: I believe you can get rid of the default link click colour with CSS and number 2 problem most likely caused by ghost click. Bind touchstart/touchend for ipad

Comment: Thanks, Huangism. I will check into that stuff. I wasn't sure if 'click' gets aliased to touchstart/touchend or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of tap colour

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

For binding, use touchstart/touchend what I have done in my current project is to detect touch, if touch enabled bind only touchstart and end, if not then bind click

I would also add a class to the anchor that you are targeting using ">a", that's really slow

```
$(#el).on('touchstart', function() {
    // if class exist
       // go to link

    // else
       // add class and open dropdown
});
```

For my current project we set up a virtual event handler to detect if the touch is a touchmove or just a regular touchstart

You can also do something like this

```
$(#el).on('touchstart', function() {
    $(this).trigger('click');
    // or you can use prevent default and stopPropagation
    return false;
});
```

or bind on touchend, whatever works better for you

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Only one small thing that I don't quite understand but will just shake my head and accept: if I click elsewhere on the screen, the menu closes. I mean, that's great behaviour and I like it, but I don't recall ever listening for clicks elsewhere and closing nav on outside clicks. ;) The CSS tip worked like a charm.

Comment: well on ipad when you tap, it's like a hover so when you tap somewhere else, it is like hovering other spots so the focus is off of the menu(assuming your menu opened on hover originally). It is best to completely separate handlers for desktop and touch device or it will get messy.

Comment: Yeah, the original nav has no handler at all (completely CSS driven on hover) so I suppose that makes sense. I'll just keep it that way for now. ;)

Comment: have fun discovering the fun bugs that comes with ipad